# Can we include any URL path for the Shapefile while creating a feature store in Deegree GIS?

Tags: shapefile, features, feature-service, deegree

I have used the Documentation and the examples of Deegree GIS application and I am able to give the path for my Shapefile in my local system, while creating a feature store just like below.

```
<ShapeFeatureStore xmlns="http://www.deegree.org/datasource/feature/shape" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" configVersion="3.4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.deegree.org/datasource/feature/shape http://schemas.deegree.org/datasource/feature/shape/3.4.0/shape.xsd">
  <StorageCRS>EPSG:26912</StorageCRS>
  <File>../../data/utah/vector/SGID93_LOCATION_UDOTMap_CityLocations</File>
</ShapeFeatureStore>
```

I am having a Shapefile in my Amazon S3 Cloud system, which can be accessed via the URL. Is there any way to include that URL anywhere in the code above, while creating a feature store ?

Comment: Interesting! I dont see why not. I think the things you would need to investigate are whether the <File> tag can handle a URL. Given its amazon as well, you would also probably need to look at other tags that can support security mechanisms (username/password, or perhaps token generation URLs or similar).